# L’oiseau-cage by Marcel Béalu

Tags: poésie

Reading the poem L’oiseau-cage by Marcel BÉALU, I don't quite get it. It sounds a wish from a child, that a beautiful place everyone he/she loves would live together happily. Is it so? or there are actually other meanings?

The full content of the poem is as below

> L’oiseau-cage
>
> -Marcel BÉALU
>
> De ce brillant plumage
> Faisons vite un oiseau
>
> Un bel oiseau tout rond
> Qui sera notre cage
>
> Un grand avion vivant
> Calfeutré comme un cœur
>
> Tous ceux que nous aimons
> Seront à l’intérieur
>
> Et par vaux et par monts
> Nos voix à l’unisson
>
> Clamerons l’allégresse
> De cet oiseau géant
>
> Dont nous serons le chant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This strikes me as a surrealist poem. The following definition, although overly simple and reductionist, can be of some help here:

> *Surrealist work:* a work of art, all the elements of which are
> recognisable as representative of real-world phenomena, but where there
> is something impossible about how those elements relate to each other.

In accordance with this, we recognise every element in the poem as being something real: the shiny feathers, the act of making something, the bird, its roundness, the cage, the big airplane, etc. However, when it comes to putting these things together, the realism evaporates: Starting with only feathers, we are asked to create a huge, round bird — an airplane, in fact — in which we can travel with our loved ones, over the hills and far away, while singing its praises.

If this resembles a dream, it’s because it probably is. Surrealist art is often seen as a reflection or interpretation of dreams, and of the subconscious generally. That also means that surrealism does not seek to convey a specific meaning: we are free to read into it whatever resonates with us. A reading of the poem as the depiction of a place of happiness for a family or a group of people who love each other absolutely makes sense, but basically any other interpretation is possible.

Comment: i like the explanation, thanks!